# Compute weighted average in one line of code

Tags: python, if-statement, lambda, list-comprehension, apply

I want to compute weighted average using one or few lines of code. It can also be in few steps.

For example at first time, compute the weighted average for All, Falcon and Parrot with V1, V2, and V3 as weight. In second step, change the weight of All using columns values as weight independently  of All, Falcon and Parrot weights

I don't want to write seperate code of each column

This is my dataframe :

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'class': ['All', 'All', 'Falcon', 'Falcon', 'Parrot', 'Parrot'],
                    'V1': [245, 362, 380., 370., 248., 269.],
                    'V2' : [356, 653, 263, 542, 456, 531],
                    'V3': [265, 378, 0, 0, 356, 541],
                    'price':[5, 2, 3, 5, 1, 5]});



Result =    V1         V2          V3
  All   3,485592316  3,46162085   3,338961039
 Falcon 3,986666667  4,346583851    
 Parrot 3,081237911  3,151975684  3,412486065
```

The weights will be in my case V1, V2 and V3 for All and the weights will be price for Falcon and Parrot

Comment: Why the one-line restriction? Python is rather intentionally designed to discourage one-liners.

Comment: Weighted by what?

Comment: @NickODell Weighed by V#

Comment: Are you trying to do this? `df2.groupby("class").apply(lambda x: pd.Series({v: ((x[v] * x['price']).sum() / x[v].sum()) for v in var_cols}))`

Comment: @AndrejKesely Divide by zero error where all values of v are zero. That's why the op has an if else.

Comment: @MatBailie In that case `pandas` will output `NaN`

Comment: It's unclear. You should elaborate on your problem. On what values should the average be calculated? And what values are the weights? Anyway I guessed. You want ```df2.groupby('class').apply(lambda x: pd.Series([np.divide(sum(x[v] * x.price), sum(x[v])) for v in var_cols]))```?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

```
weight_cols = ['V1', 'V2', 'V3']

df.groupby('class') \
   .apply(
    lambda frame: \
        frame[weight_cols].multiply(frame['price'], axis='index').sum(axis=0) \
            .multiply(1/frame[weight_cols].sum(axis=0))) \
  .reset_index(drop=False) \
  .rename({weight_col: f'price_weighted_average_{weight_col.lower()}' for weight_col in weight_cols}, axis=1)
```